# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage - isPresent listener? event handler?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can i handle or know when the Master page opens/closes and handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have a event for that, IsPresentedChanged , you can check the api documentation:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3aXamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.IsPresentedChanged